How to create an automation to send the secret securely to corresponding individuals from secret manager?
The Secret are stored in secret manager. The email-id are present with the secrets. How we can create an automation for this to send the secrets securely to corresponding individuals to the associated email id??
Else, how we can send the secret to corresponding individuals instead of email ??
Trying to create a workflow or some automation for this.
